Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" block of
I updated Flutter and got this error, what should I do? I changed the Kotlin version, it still didn't work, how can I solve this problem?
I changed the Kotlin version number in Settings.Gradle, but it didn't work. This happened after the last update in Flutter. I can only build on Windows, so I can't build only on Android.

Try to add ext.kotlin_version in android/build.gradle as mentioned in this answer.
